# cpanm vs apt upgrades

Tags: debian, perl, upgrade

I'm updating my Perl modules. I've found this command elsewhere:

```
cpan-outdated -p | cpanm
```

I'm wondering if this won't bring in any conflicts with my Debian's apt-installed Perl modules. I had this kind of adventures with Python's `pip`. Is there anything in particular to be wary of? Or are they safely isolated schemes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package [`cpan-outdated`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/cpanoutdated) is maintained by Debian it can be used without any risk. The perl script can be found [on git repository](https://github.com/tokuhirom/cpan-outdated/blob/master/script/cpan-outdated).

> script to detect outdated CPAN modules in your environment
>
> `cpanoutdated` prints the list of outdated CPAN modules in your machine. It provides the same feature as `'CPAN::Shell->r'`, but `cpan-outdated` is much faster and uses less memory. This script can be integrated with the cpanm command.

It can be used to list  the outdated Perl modules:

```
cpan-outdated -p
```

And upgrade them:

```
cpan-outdated | cpanm
```

or:

```
cpan-outdated -p | cpanm
```

A similar command to `apt-listchanges` can be used to inspect the changes between Perl modules versions: the [`cpan-listchanges`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/cpan-listchanges) , it can be integrated with the `cpan-outdated` command.

```
cpan-listchanges `cpan-outdated -p`
```

> package change history notification tool
>
> `cpan-listchanges` is a command-line application that compares the Changes file between arbitrary versions of a package. It is similar to `apt-listchanges`, and by default, it compares the currently installed version with the latest one available on CPAN.

Comment: `pip` is also maintained by Debian. Still, I got problems with it (upgrading with pip broke my apt installed Python dependencies). The question is whether the `apt` Perl modules and the modules from `cpan/m` (not sure how they go along) don't come into collisions. I can't find their relation explained in your answer.

Comment: @tomasz Installing a broken package (module) with `pip` , `cpan` .... and also with `apt` will end-up with a broken `apt`

Comment: Ok, so there's only one common structure in this scenario?

Comment: @tomasz Installing a  Perl module  (excluding the buggy modules) using `cpan` or `apt` (if the module is packaged ) is the same .

Comment: Well, they're different... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728216/purpose-of-installing-a-perl-module-with-apt-get-instead-of-cpan

Comment: @tomasz You don't need the root access to install perl modules using  `cpan`, The `apt` install modules to the `*/perl5/` directory with root privilege , if `cpan` .... and `apt` install the Perl module in the same location , only the root users can use `cpan` .

Comment: @GAD3R no, installing modules using CPAN or `apt` isn’t the same; for one thing modules installed using CPAN aren’t tracked as packages.

Comment: @StephenKitt (And at GAD3R too.) I will wait for a more complete answer then. I'm not convinced as to the interconnections between the modules. What if I double-install the same module (possibly in different versions) through both apt and cpan?

Comment: @tomasz GAD3R’s *answer* is correct, it’s only his comment which causes issue (unfortunately comments can’t be downvoted). Debian’s Perl configures the various site settings appropriately so that CPAN installs in `/usr/local` (if run as root); that way, you can install modules from CPAN without affecting anything that the package manager deals with. However installing a Perl module using `apt` isn’t the same as installing it with CPAN. See the [Debian Perl FAQ](https://wiki.debian.org/PerlFAQ) for details.

Comment: @tomasz another way to think of all this is to consider that packaged libraries, including Perl modules, are primarily there to provide required dependencies for end-user applications. If you’re developing using Perl, and the packaged Perl modules suit you, then you can most certainly use them for that as well. However it’s perfectly OK to require non-packaged modules, or newer versions, and to install those using CPAN, either into `/usr/local` (which *might* have adverse effects if a module is upwardly-incompatible), your home directory, or, better yet, some sort of virtual environment.